# Storyboard Table View Controller not displaying user defined music list

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, storyboard

I may be missing something really obvious but:
I'm trying to migrate a project into Storyboards, however im struggling to get my table view controller to display data that the user has defined.

Basically, the project uses a media picker to create a queue of songs, for which the app is playing perfectly. my trouble begins when i try to display this User defined list in a table view, its simply not displaying any info at all! (my old .xib file worked ok!) .

my .h of the table view controller:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
#import "MusicViewController.h"

@protocol MusicTableViewControllerDelegate; // forward declaration

@interface MusicTableViewController : UITableViewController     <MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate, UITableViewDelegate> {

__unsafe_unretained id <MusicTableViewControllerDelegate>   delegate;

}


@property (nonatomic, assign) id <MusicTableViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *mediaItemCollectionTable;

@end

@protocol MusicTableViewControllerDelegate

// implemented in MainViewController.m
- (void) musicTableViewControllerDidFinish: (MusicTableViewController *) controller;
- (void) updatePlayerQueueWithMediaCollection: (MPMediaItemCollection *) mediaItemCollection;

@end
```

and my .m:

```
#import "MusicTableViewController.h"
#import "MusicViewController.h"

@interface MusicTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation MusicTableViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {

}
return self;
}

@synthesize delegate;           // The main view controller is the delegate for this class.
@synthesize mediaItemCollectionTable;   // The table shown in this class's view.


// Configures the table view>
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{

 // Return the number of sections.
 return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of rows in the section.

MusicViewController *mainViewController = (MusicViewController *) self.delegate;
MPMediaItemCollection *currentQueue = mainViewController.userMediaItemCollection;

return [currentQueue.items count];


}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


if (cell == nil) {

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                 reuseIdentifier: @"Cell"];

}

MusicViewController *mainViewController = (MusicViewController *) self.delegate;
MPMediaItemCollection *currentQueue = mainViewController.userMediaItemCollection;
MPMediaItem *anItem = (MPMediaItem *)[currentQueue.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [anItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];

return cell;
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath: indexPath animated: YES];

@end
```

Im at a complete miss as to why its not returning anything!

Comment: I would put `NSLog(@"Controller: %@, Queue: %@, Items: %@, Count: %d", mainViewController, currentQueue, currentQueue.items, [currentQueue.items count]);` just before `return [currentQueue.items count];` and see what I got.

Comment: ill give that a shot actually! good thinking!

Comment: Funnily enough it returns "0". At least i can stop putting efforts into this part. :)

Comment: Just empty as opposed to a nil for controller, queue, or items?

Comment: Actual Output: Controller: (null), Queue: (null), Items: (null), Count: 0

Comment: There is definitely a queue - my music view one step before in the storyboard is successfully picking them from a mediapicker and playing them in order.

Comment: So, presumably, the delegate isn't being set to a valid object since that's the earliest nil one in the chain.

Comment: It must be! It did pull it successfully when it was a xib. I've also switched to ARC, so there's probably something I'm doing not quite right. Thanks for your help - I have a good idea of where to target my efforts now! :)

Comment: I worked this out in the end! - It transpires i needed to use a Prepare for Segue to push the data to the table. :)

Answer (score 0):

In storyboard, check if your table's content is set to Static Cells if it is, change it to Dynamic Prototypes.

Also, in your code, in cellForRowAtIndexPath, where have you declared the onbject 'cell'. I see direct comparison `if(cell == nil)` it is not declared anywhere.

Comment: Cheers! - Cell was declared ok in the Identifier field in the interface builder inspector.

Answer (score 0):

I worked this out in the end! - It transpires i needed to use a Prepare for Segue to push the data to the table as a result of transferring the app to Storyboard based.